# Neo4j CREATE UNIQUE always creates completely new path?

Tags: neo4j, unique, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to Neo4j and am trying to create a tree with CREATE UNIQUE to reuse the existing branches (adding leaves/limbs) but the problem is:

A new path will always be created if I run the same query multiple times. That is:

If I run:

```
START r=node:root(root_name="foo")
CREATE UNIQUE (r)-[r1:KNOWS]->(n1:Person {name:"n1"})-[r2:KNOWS]->(n2:Person {name:"n2"})-[r3:KNOWS]->(n3:Person {name:"n3"})
RETURN (n3)
```

multiple times, every time a completely new branch will be created instead of reusing the previously created path.

Is this the intended behavior or did I misunderstand it, please? How may I add new leaves/limbs while reusing the existing part of the branch then?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post how have you indexed your nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of some problem in the way you have indexed your nodes.

You can try below

```
MATCH (root:Person {name: "foo"})
CREATE UNIQUE (root)-[r1:KNOWS]->(n1:Person {name:"n1"})-[r2:KNOWS]->(n2:Person {name:"n2"})-[r3:KNOWS]->(n3:Person {name:"n3"})
RETURN n3
```